# Dishwasher Discolored Mess Kit

Tags: camping

I have 2 aluminum mess kits.  One is a Boy Scout branded one from the 90's and the other I just bought recently for my son.  Both was bright and shinny metal but I put them in the dishwasher before a weekend camping trip, and they came out discolored and darkened unevenly.  I have always had a dishwasher, so I'm puzzled as to what happened to the older one.  I haven't used the kit in a long time so I can't recall if it ever went into the dishwasher when I was using it.  Why did they discolor, how can I fix it, and did I ruin them functionally?

Answer (score 6):

It just oxidized the aluminum.  A hard scrubbing will remove the oxidation.  Just use a [green scrubby](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004E2RXPA).  If you need extra abrasive that is safe, tooth paste will usually work.

Comment: We did this to a stand mixer attachment just a few months back.  Luckily for the OP, you've *added* something to the aluminum that can be taken away.  Green scrubby and elbow grease will do the trick. :)

Comment: @ClareSteen note that when removing the oxidation, you do remove some aluminum too.

Comment: The specific cause of the oxidation is usually the aluminum being in contact with steel during the washing.

Comment: @Mark -- We've had things oxidize without touching any other metals, so unless there's steel in the water... I'm skeptical :)